# wxWidgets - error: conversion from 'wxCStrData' to non-scalar type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' requested

Tags: type-conversion, wxwidgets

in my project I try to use the following line to get a string value:

```
string azonosito=ItemID->GetLabelText().c_str();
```

but it doesn't work, and this doesn't either:

```
string tipus=CategoryFilter->GetString(CategoryFilter->GetCurrentSelection()).c_str();
```

error: conversion from 'wxCStrData' to non-scalar type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' requested

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 and wxWidgets TDM 4.8.1., but this Code::Blocks can fully execute a project that was written in older wxWidgets version, with a totally same conversion method. 
What could be the problem?

Any comments and tips are welcome,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c_str()` returns a polymorphic object convertible to either `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`, so in case of ambiguity you need to select what exactly do you need. However in this case, you can avoid this ambiguity completely by doing

```
std::string azonosito(ItemID->GetLabelText().c_str());
```

or, even more clearly,

```
std::string azonosito(ItemID->GetLabelText().ToStdString());
```